# Java Error "Unable to Find Symbol" with Android

Tags: java, android, android-activity

So I am attempting to make an Android App, but when I try to compile my project, I get the error:

```
DisplayMessageActivity.java :2 :Error - cannot find symbol
"public class DisplayMessageActivity extends Activity {"

symbol: class Activity
```

Here is my source code for DisplayMessageActivity.java(it's parent is MainActivity.java, which imports the android.app.Activity and android.os.Bundle packages):

```
public class DisplayMessageActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Get the message from the intent
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    // Create the text view
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(message);

    // Set the text view as the activity layout
    setContentView(textView);
}
}
```

Here is the AndroidManifest.xml file-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.example.HelloWorld"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <activity android:name="MainActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android.value="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Please help,

Niro56

Comment: You should still import `Activity`, etc in the child class.

Answer (score 3):

You need to import `Activity` as `import android.app.Activity` in the top of your file after package declaration.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add "package com.example.myfirstapp;" at the top of my DisplayMessageActivity.java file to get past this compilation error.  I also had to add an import of android.widget.TextView to get past the next "symbol not found" error.